# How do you specify day and time with quarterly schedules in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, cron, laravel-5

The docs seem to say that the only option is `quarterly()->when(function() {...});`

Is this reliable? It seems to run through each job's time functions each time the scheduler runs, which I guess is every minute. Is this not problematic?

Answer (score 0):

If you look under the hood you'll see that the quarterly function just calls the cron method (see below).  In this case it will run on the first minute of the first hour every three months.  The format of the cron string can be found here https://serverfault.com/a/601660 if you wish to customise your schedule further.

```
/**
 * Schedule the event to run quarterly.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function quarterly()
{
    return $this->cron('0 0 1 */3 *');
}
```

Comment: I saw that, but I guess I should ask if it is every three months, or every third month?

Comment: The `*/3` means every third month from the start of the year. So it will run in Jan, Apr, Jul, Oct.